# Operations for equivalent interest rates not giving expected result

Tags: python, operators, operation

I am trying to calculate equivalent interest rates like [this site](https://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/financial/equivalent-interest-rate-calculator.php?ratepercent=3&m=12&q=4&action=solve) and while I believe I wrote all operations correctly I am not getting the same results as the site.

```
def equivalent_interest_rate(q,r,m):
    return q*((1+(r/m))**(m/q)-1)

print(equivalent_interest_rate(3,12,4))
```

Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: Please post your output and the number expected so that its all clear in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pay attention to the order and the units.

```
def equivalent_interest_rate(r,m,q):
    return q*((1+(r/m))**(m/q)-1)

print(equivalent_interest_rate(0.03,12,4))
```

-> 0.030075062499999028

[image]